# Locate the #define that breaks the compilation

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am having a situation where #define in one of the header files breaks an enum declaration in another header file.

Using `-E` switch on `gcc` I've established that I have

```
#define OFF 0
```

somewhere.

Question is, how do I find out where? The project is huge, dozens of include directories, hundreds of include files. I'll do a global grep eventually, but the question is, is there any way to ask the `gcc` compiler where #define occurs? It obviously has that information!

Update: thanks for not one but two solutions - SO comes through.
Just for the record, the culprit was one of the Sybase client libraries' includes (ctlib, not even dblib). Ouch.

Comment: Use grep. Just use grep.

Comment: To elaboaraate, you can do the following : "grep -r '#define OFF' ./"

Comment: It does. But only if you ask nicely and use the magic word. Absent that, it's gonna be grep.

Comment: A recursive grep command most likely would have completed before you finished typing this question.  "dozens of include directories, hundreds of include files" is *not* huge.

Comment: My #includes come from a dozen different subtrees in a few filesytems. Just locating them all is a non-trivial task due to all included makefiles. We're talking an "enterprise" project here, folks :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can redefine it (to a different value). Then the gcc will tell you where it is already defined.

On my system it looks like this:

> In file included from < some file >:27,
>
> ```
>              from < another file >:13:
> ```
>
> < header file with the redefined value>:30:1: > warning: "< the define >" redefined
>
> < command-line >: warning: this is the location of the previous
>   definition

Answer (score 5):

Use the option -dD together with -E. With both enabled you see the preprocessing result including the defines. Just look for you macro (like #define OFF 1) and scroll up, to the `# number filename`, and you find the last include file, so it was the one, that defined your macro.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is to run something like "ctags", which essentially builds a database of symbols defined in your code.  Many popular editors (vim, emacs) will then read the tags file and let you quickly jump to definitions by name.  For example, using vim I would simply type:

```
:ta myfunction
```

To find the definition of `myfunction`.  This works equally well for macros created with `#define`, and it supports a variety of languages other than C.  I'm using [exhuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), which is what you get if you install `ctags` on a RHEL-ish system, but it's certainly available under Debian, Ubuntu, OS X, and so forth.

Comment: On Ubuntu (and probably Debian): `apt-get install exuberant-ctags`