# Use gcc or cpp to search for the location of defines

Tags: c++, location, c-preprocessor

I got lots of sources files with their different separate folders. For one **C** file, I can use the cpp to generate a list showing me all the defines this **C** file needs. But I can't find a possibility to let the Cpp show me where these defines are located.

Does someone have a idea?

Comment: When you say "defines" do you mean as in `#define`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use grep to search your source files for the original #define. This is explored in more detail in [Locate the #define that breaks the compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934701/locate-the-define-that-breaks-the-compilation)